# Encode "k out of n labels" feature in sklearn/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a feature that is a subset of a set of labels.

```
>>> labels = ['ini', '', 'pdf', 'flac', 'php']
>>> data = [random.sample(labels, random.randint(0, len(labels))) for _ in range(20)]
>>> data[:5]
[['pdf'], [], ['pdf', 'flac'], ['php', 'pdf', 'ini'], ['', 'php', 'ini']]
```

I need a "k out of n encoder" to encode this feature. I tried using/hacking OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder, get_dummies but couldn't represent this data well. The set of labels may not be known ahead of time.

In pure python, the (slow) implementation could be -

```
>>>> feature_space = sorted(list(set(sum(data, []))))
>>>> data2 = [[int(c in row) for c in feature_space] for row in data]
>>> data2[:5]
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Is there a pandas or sklearn function/pipeline to encode such a feature?

Answer (score 2):

Use a pandas series to track your labels in its index.  Then access the values of `1` via the `.loc` method.  Fill in the missing values with `0`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series(np.ones(len(labels)), labels)
s0 = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(labels)), labels)

df = pd.concat([s1.loc[d].combine_first(s0) for d in data], axis=1)
df.astype(int).T[labels].values
```

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3,1415])
labels = ['ini', '', 'pdf', 'flac', 'php']
data = [random.sample(labels, random.randint(0, len(labels))) for _ in range(20)]

s1 = pd.Series(np.ones(len(labels)), labels)
s0 = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(labels)), labels)
```

#### Validate

`data[0]` is empty

```
data[0]

[]
```

---

Slicing `s1` with it yields an empty series.

```
s1.loc[data[0]]

Series([], dtype: float64)
```

---

Combining with `s0` fills in with 0
    s1.loc[data[0]].combine_first(s0)

```
        0.0
flac    0.0
ini     1.0
pdf     0.0
php     0.0
dtype: float64
```

---

`pd.concat` to get them all together.

```
df = pd.concat([s1.loc[d].combine_first(s0) for d in data], axis=1).T

print df.head()

       flac  ini  pdf  php
0   0     0    1    0    0
1   0     0    0    0    1
2   1     1    0    1    1
3   0     1    0    0    0
4   0     0    0    1    0
```

---

Slice by labels to get correct order back and take values

```
df.astype(int)[labels].values

array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: This looks promising, but it ignores empty set data points (like data[1] in my example(

Comment: Note that the labels are not known beforehand (I created that list to create the data). Is there a better (better than set(sum(data, [])) way to discover all the labels? May be using LabelEncoder or get_dummies?

Comment: Use `pd.Series(pd.DataFrame(data).values.flatten()).dropna().unique()`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a similar way to encode another form of feature where instead of a set, we have a dict of counts? for example, [{"":1, "pdf":20}, {"ini":2, "php":3}]

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([{"":1, "pdf":20}, {"ini":2, "php":3}]).columns.tolist()`